# compiling and linking openAL with mingw?

Tags: audio, gcc, g++, mingw, openal

How do I compile the following [example](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-guide-to-starting-with-openal-r2008) from gamedev using mingw?. I've installed the openAl SDK to `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenAL 1.1 SDK` and I have mingw and msys installed in `C:\MinGW` and `C:\msys`.

I'm not sure how to compile this or what to link. I've looked at the docs but they don't specify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "download sample ZIP" link on that page gives me a 404, and the snippets in the article are not complete.

In addition to concatenating the snippets, you will at the very least need to add `#include` directives for `al/al.h` and `al/alc.h` in order to compile.

To link the program, you will need to link against the OpenAL import library which is called `libOpenAL32.dll.a` on my system. You may alternatively find `OpenAL32.lib` (the MSVC version, which still should work) or only the DLL file on your system.
--- I have both OpenAL-Soft (in 3 different builds) and the Creatix one on my system, which makes choosing the correct import lib an endeavour (even more so as manufacturers tend to always give these similar, confusing names).

Which leads to the solution that I am using: **Link directly to the DLL**. Luckily, MinGW will (other than most other compilers) do that kind of thing just fine :-)

For example, I just add `-l"z:/lib/soft_oal113-sse41.dll"` to the linker's commandline to link with that particular version, and it just does that without any complaints, no import libraries needed, no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other responder said, you should be able to just download and use their binaries.  If you do end up wanting to build OpenAL using mingw, according to 
http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/local.html#openalsoft

(install cmake first)

cd build

cmake.exe -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..

make

GL!